# Ping hangs and internet fails with particular connection and machine on Debian Testing

Tags: debian, networking

I have two laptops with Debian Testing installed; let's call them Laptop1 and Laptop2. On Laptop1 the wireless device is `Wireless 1: 07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)` from `lspci`; on Laptop2 it is `Wireless 2: 02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)`. Both run kernel 5.15.5-2. Both machines have a MTU size of 1500.

Laptop1 connects to the internet with no problem,
both wireless and via Ethernet cable. 
Laptop2, however, has a problem with the internet service I have at home. 
The problem happens only with this particular laptop *and* my ISP's connections, *both wireless and Ethernet*. 
Here's what happens
when I ping `8.8.8.8` on that laptop connected to my ISP's networks:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=556 time=31.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=556 time=32.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=556 time=37.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=556 time=32.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=32 ttl=556 time=248 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=33 ttl=556 time=32.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=34 ttl=556 time=34.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=35 ttl=556 time=32.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=36 ttl=556 time=32.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=107 ttl=556 time=611 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=108 ttl=556 time=32.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=109 ttl=556 time=32.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=110 ttl=556 time=33.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=111 ttl=556 time=32.0 ms
```

<sup>[Manually transcribed from [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUgLm.png).]</sup> 
This doesn't happen with other connections
(I tried with another network here at home,
provided by an employer, and at a café).

As you can see, when I ping I receive a burst of 4 or 5 packets,
and then many packets are dropped. 
The first packet after a break in connectivity
has a very large round-trip time. 
This repeats indefinitely. 
I can run `traceroute google.com` successfully. 
Also, when I try to browse using Firefox,
I always get "connection timed out",
whereas the internet is slow on Edge (Linux) and w3m;
it fails in the latter browsers,
but I can sometimes connect to and browse sites. 
I am currently posting from Laptop1,
but I can provide information from Laptop2 if needed.

I tried running `dpkg-reconfigure network-manager`, and deleting all connections in the Network Manager GUI but the problem persists. 
This issue is not specific to this kernel version;
the same happens with kernel 5.14.16-1.

Is this a Network Manager issue, or is it something else?

EDIT FOR UPDATE:

I noticed that on Laptop2, while connected to my ISP's network, I can't ping any address in the local network (i.e. `192.168.100.x`; they all return "Destination Host Unreachable"), excepting `x=1` which is the router/switch in which I can see all connected devices, etc. If I ping this latter address without any trouble. Also, I cannot ping the IP for Laptop2 (last try was `192.168.100.58`) from any other device; it always returns "Destination host unreachable". Further, on Laptop2 I can't log into the router config page (`192.168.100.1`), while I can on Laptop1 and on my phone; when I enter this address in any browser, I see the Debian Apache page (the file is `/var/www/html/index.html`).

Immediately after establishing a connection with my ISP's network I can browse, but after around 15 seconds every request hangs; I can still ping but `traceroute` always returns all asterisks. I [followed this instructions](https://linoxide.com/how-to-flush-routing-table-from-cache/) to flush routing tables, as per some advice I got on a Facebook group, but the problem persists. Also, I deleted all files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` and restarted Network Manager, but still nothing. If relevant, `/etc/resolv.conf` gives `192.168.100.1` as the Name Server (which makes a lot of sense to me).

When trying to edit the parameters for Laptop2 at the switch's page (`192.168.100.1`), it always says it is offline, no matter whether or not it is connected to the access point. I tried adding Laptop2's wireless MAC address to the whitelist and changing its IP address, but the problem persists. Right now I'm on Laptop2 using another network.

Comment: (1) [Please post text as text.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/80216 "PSA: Please don't post images of text")  (I transcribed your screenshot for you; please proofread it and fix any errors I might have introduced.)  If you must post an image, please upload it through the Stack Exchange editor so it goes to i.stack.imgur.com. (2) You say that the problem is specific to Laptop2, but you don’t say anything about having tested Laptop1 (or any other machine) at home.  An obvious diagnosis is that your home Internet connection (and/or your modem / router) is defective,  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  especially since Laptop2 works with other network connections. … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Thanks. Laptop1 works well with all networks, as I stated in the second paragraph. I edited the post to give more information.